# decode a malware found on server obfuscated like a array of characters in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, encoding, malware

Today I've found a malware on one site, I have deleted it, of course, and everything is ok, but in order to understand where it comes from, I would like to understand its logic, but it is encoded, in a quite easy way. At the beginning of the file I see:

```
$i96="QU~T<`_YM82iAN>/v#s\"'q@tZFjJX6a\tcI)yS^boD.\$du|3\rWw=rC!;[4*P5LVkB?%19m:p7 -zK,gOl{Efx]0R}&h+\n\\(enGH";
```

This is used then in all the rest of the file, as a dictionary of characters, from now on, there are all assignments like this:

```
$GLOBALS['rpdxi45'] = $i96[94].$i96[51].$i96[51].$i96[39].$i96[51].$i96[6].$i96[51].$i96[94].$i96[70].$i96[39].$i96[51].$i96[23].$i96[11].$i96[95].$i96[77];
```

Does anyone has a clue on how I can decode this (without infecting a server of mine, of course), or at least has the name of this type of encryption? Just to know if I can find something on the web.

If someone is interested, I can post the rest of the file, I found it odd.

Update: the file is actually a malicious shell hack. If you find it on your server, delete it and contact your sysadmin.

Comment: Just replace any eval() functions with var_dump() and take a look at the output. You can run php on sites like codepad.viper-7.com if you are worried. For example the code above creates the string "error_reporting"

Comment: +1 for Steve. Doesn't appear to be malware at all.

Comment: A simple character replacement says it means just about as much nonsense as the original string.  In any case, this cannot be the whole thing.  Where is the $GLOBALS array being used?

Comment: it IS indeed a malware, yesterday the file isn't there, today it is, google flagged it as malware as much as the hosting company... after deleting it the hosting company has opened again the host.
P.S. I don't get the meaning of the downvotes, if downvote, please take a minute to explain "why", thanks.

Comment: This isn't encryption, its obfuscation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obfuscating the phrase "error_reporting"

```
<?php
$i96="QU~T<`_YM82iAN>/v#s\"'q@tZFjJX6a\tcI)yS^boD.\$du|3\rWw=rC!;[4*P5LVkB?%19m:p7 -zK,gOl{Efx]0R}&h+\n\\(enGH";
echo $i96[94].$i96[51].$i96[51].$i96[39].$i96[51].$i96[6].$i96[51].$i96[94].$i96[70].$i96[39].$i96[51].$i96[23].$i96[11].$i96[95].$i96[77];
```

`$GLOBALS['rpdxi45']` is storing a string constructed from the characters of the string held in `$i96`.

Echoing `$GLOBALS['rpdxi45']` will show you the string that has been constructed.

See here: http://ideone.com/Jy1uty